# Simple Calculator.. trying to add a loop

Tags: java, performance

So this is my code for a simple calculator. It works for the most part, and I'm trying to create a loop at the end of the operation to allow a user the chance to choose to do another operation or exit. So far I've tried adding a nested if loop but I keep getting an error. Any help would be helpful. I'm fairly new.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Introduction to Calculator providing instructions to user
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1, num2, ans, Y, N;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Simple Calculator: Please enter \n" + 
                    "which mathimatical operation you would like to \n "
                    + "accomplish by imputing 1-addition, 2-subtraction \n"
                    + "3-multiplication, 4-division, 5-modulo");

    int Operation = input.nextInt();

    //Operation sequence for user to input which operation they would like to accomplish


    if (Operation == 1) {
        System.out.println("You have Choosen Addition");
        System.out.print("Enter your First number: ");
        num1 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        ans = num1 + num2;
        System.out.print("Answer is: " + ans);

        /*
         * Right here in the following I want to put something in to make this loop
         * so the user can make multiple calculation.
         * So far nothing has worked.
         */
        System.out.println("Would you like to do another calculation?\n " +
                            "Enter Y for Yes or N to Exit");


    }else if (Operation == 2){

        System.out.println("You have Choosen Subtraction");
        System.out.print("Enter your First number: ");
        num1 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        ans = num1 - num2;
        System.out.print("Answer is: " + ans);


    }else if (Operation == 3){

        System.out.println("You have Choosen Multiplication");
        System.out.print("Enter your First number: ");
        num1 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        ans = num1 * num2;
        System.out.print("Answer is: " + ans);



    }else if (Operation == 4){

        System.out.println("You have Choosen Division");
        System.out.print("Enter your First number: ");
        num1 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        ans = num1 / num2;
        System.out.print("Answer is: " + ans);


    }else if (Operation == 5){
        System.out.println("You have Choosen Modulo");
        System.out.print("Enter your First number: ");
        num1 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = (int) input.nextDouble();

        ans = num1 % num2;
        System.out.print("Answer is: " + ans);

    }else{
        System.out.print("Invalid Operation, please try again.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `but I keep getting an error.` And you don't think the error you're getting might be an important part of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track here. I would suggest using a do-while loop. So encase the entire part beginning with `if (Operation == 1) {` all the way down to your final `else` statement like this:

```
do {
    /*
        if (Operation == 1) {
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
        else {
                 ...
        }
    */
    System.out.print("Would you like to do another calculation? [Y/n] ");
} while (input.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y');
```

Comment: I'll have to try that, this might actually solve a problem on one of my other programs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the entire thing in a while loop and at the end ask if they want to continue
yes - it goes back through the loop
no - you have it break out of the loop